# Images not found on iis7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I am moving an old asp classic (sigh...) local website to a new IIS7.5 server. The asp code renders fine, but the images don't show up.

This mini website is located on a virtual directory under the Default Web Site.

My guess was it's a permissions issue, so I've added the IIS_IUSRS group to the permissions of the folder, both under the IIS manager and on the windows explorer, but the images still don't show up. Do I need to restart the server after such a change?

In an effort to debug this, I've created the simplest "hello world" html file, and that didn't render at all. After saving the very same file with an asp extension, it now renders fine.

So my server doesn't show html files, and doesn't show images, but does show asp  classic files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What messages are in the server logs?

Comment: hmmm... where do I find the server logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!

Turns out I had to enable "Static Content" on the iis. Now it serves images and plain html pages just fine.

[image: screen shot]